# Javascript timer not correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I'm trying to time a ajax request, but I get random elapsed time:

```
startTime = new Date();  

$.ajax({
 ...
 success: function(response){

   endTime = new Date();
   timeDiff = endTime - startTime; 
   elapsed = Math.round(timeDiff % 60);

   alert(elapsed + ' seconds elapsed');
 }
}
```

...Like after 2 seconds I get 36 seconds, or 59 seconds, or 1 second etc..

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Use `/` instead of `%`

`%` is [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator.

Proper code to calculate number of seconds between to dates:

```
(endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

Date - Date returns milliseconds.  Lets say your request takes one second, so `timediff = 1000`.  You then do a `1000 % 60`, which is `40` and not what you want...

I think you want this:

```
elapsed = Math.round(timeDiff / 1000);
```

Which will convert milliseconds to seconds.

The modulo operator `%` return the remainder of a division operation which is not something you appear to be after...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 0):

Add a `+` sign to both versions of `new Date()`:

```
startTime = +new Date();
```

That will guarantee that the date is converted into a numerical value (timestamp) which you can do the substraction operation with. It looks like it does work without, but I don't know what that will do some in browsers/versions implementations.

Also as mentioned in other answers, you need to divide the result (which is in miliseconds) by `1000` to get the seconds.